# Is it possible to create a plugin for VLC in C#?

Tags: c#, plugins, module, vlc

Is it possible to write a plugin in C# for Video Lan Player for windows, without compiling the VLC player?
Most of what I've seen has been C++ code and I'm much stronger in C#.

Imagine this scenario:
- I would like to write a playback plugin where two or more people have the same video stream.
- All parties need to have the same stream (DVD or vídeo file):

User A hits pause and it stops on all screens and the viewing starts when User A returns and hits play.

- Is this possible with UDP calls?

Comment: You could use [VLC HTTP requests][https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/] to control many VLC at the same time. But will be an external tool and not a plugin.

Comment: You should take a look at the existing netsync module written in C which is doing exactly what you are describing (yes, using UDP).